# How to retrieve the type and product information of the barcode

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I have created a barcode scanner which invokes zxing barcode scanner via intent. It retrieves the result code and scan_result_format. How can I retrieve the type (like text or product) from zxing barcode scanner. I also want to retrieve the product information like name,price. I searched and found solutions for this, but it was very confusing.

this is my code.:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
      switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.butQR:
          intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        break;
        case R.id.butProd:
          intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
        break;
        case R.id.butOther:
          intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR");
        break;
      }
      startActivityForResult(intent, 0);    //Barcode Scanner to scan for us
    }
  }
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
  {
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {   

     TextView tvStatus=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
      TextView tvResult=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
      {
        Intent intent1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Display.class);
        intent1.putExtra("result_format", intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
        intent1.putExtra("result", intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
          startActivity(intent1);
      } 
      else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) 
      {
        tvStatus.setText("Press a button to start a scan.");
        tvResult.setText("Scan cancelled.");
      }
    }
```

Comment: if I don´t understand you the wrong way, You want to read product information from barcode? A barcode is usually only a number, if you think on a barcode from a good you can buy in the warehouse. Sure it is possible to set informations inside the barcode like product details, but this is not the way they do it. Often they set only an id number in that barcode that is gonna be linked with a database with product details.

Comment: ok. It means the barcode contains only numbers?

Comment: And how to retrive the barcode type? using zxing

Comment: not mandatory, for sure you can set for example "Bread 1,15 USD" and read this from a barcode, but this is not common. So mostly You will get only a number. If You want to build an app that will generate a custom barcode, it is possible. But if You want to build an app that reads every barcode, you will get less success. It is long time ago, that I build an java application to generate barcode with zxing, I will look at it this weekend and try to give You an example.

Comment: One thing: You know the barcodes where you can get linked to an app? In that barcode the Uri is stored. This is a good example for barcodes not used with code numbers.

Comment: hI, before getting to deep into, just want to know if it could help. could You give me your email adress so I will send you the java application I made to generate a qr code. Then you could generate one and scan it with your device and give me some feedback if this could help you...

Comment: here is my email add:  manasibarwe1991@gmail.com